# Missing variables in geom_point() with no NAs

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've run into an issue where, despite each variable having data associated with it, 8 of my rows (in this example, locations of isotope samples) aren't being plotted.

I have a dataset, a tibble named Comp_Salmon

```
  Catch_Location_Site       Group                 Mean_D13C D13C_SD Mean_D15N D15N_SD Species    
   <chr>                     <chr>                     <dbl>   <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl> <chr>      
 1 River Sella - Spain       Modern Europe             -16.5    0.3      10.7     0.4  Salmo salar
 2 River Bush - Ireland      Modern Europe             -15.6    0.7      10.4     0.86 Salmo salar
 3 River Dee - England/Wales Modern Europe             -16.2    0.7       9.1     0.7  Salmo salar
 4 River Frome - England     Modern Europe             -16.3    0.6       9.9     1    Salmo salar
 5 Northeast UK Coast        Modern Europe             -15.9    0.8       9.7     1.1  Salmo salar
 6 River Sella - Spain       Modern Europe             -16.2    0.6      12       0.9  Salmo salar
 7 River Bush - Ireland      Modern Europe             -15.8    0.5      11       0.8  Salmo salar
 8 River Dee - England/Wales Modern Europe             -16.4    0.4      10.6     0.7  Salmo salar
 9 River Frome - England     Modern Europe             -16.8    0.5      11.4     0.8  Salmo salar
10 Northeast UK Coast        Modern Europe             -15.9    0.8      10.5     0.8  Salmo salar
11 Koksoak River             Modern Canada             -21.6    0.8      11.9     0.5  Salmo salar
12 Koksoak River             Modern Canada             -20.6    0.6      13.4     1.6  Salmo salar
13 Conne River               Modern Canada             -20.5    0.4      12.8     0.4  Salmo salar
14 River Erne - Ireland      Modern Europe             -18.9    0.5      10.7     0.5  Salmo salar
15 Conne River               Modern Canada             -15.4    0.17     11.2     0.48 Salmo salar
16 Big Salmon River          Modern Canada             -13.7    0.2      10.3     0.4  Salmo salar
17 River Bush - Ireland      Modern Europe             -15.5    0.5      11.6     0.7  Salmo salar
18 River Dee - England/Wales Modern Europe             -15.5    0.3      11.3     0.3  Salmo salar
19 Gaspereau River           Modern Canada             -15.3    0.3      11.6     0.6  Salmo salar
20 Upper Salmon River        Modern Canada             -14.0    0.4      11.1     1.9  Salmo salar
21 Northeast UK Coast        Modern Europe             -15.9    1.05     10       1.96 Salmo salar
22 Northeast UK Coast        Modern Europe             -16      1.13     10.4     1.74 Salmo salar
23 Loch Ness - Scotland      Modern Europe             -19.5    1        10.7     0.8  Salmo salar
24 Gulf of St. Lawrence      Modern Canada             -16.5    0        10.8     0.1  Salmo salar
25 Gulf of St. Lawrence      Modern Canada             -16.3    0        11       0.1  Salmo salar
26 Gulf of St. Lawrence      Modern Canada             -16.3    0        12.1     0.2  Salmo salar
27 Baffin Bay - Greenland    Modern Europe             -16.9    0        10.6     0    Salmo salar
28 Coppergate - England      North Sea Basin           -14.5    0.49      9.76    0.8  Salmo salar
29 Netherlands               North Sea Basin           -15.1    0.25     10.1     1.3  Salmo salar
30 Ribe - Denmark            North Sea Basin           -16.3    0        12.0     0    Salmo salar
31 Earl's Bu - Scotland      North Sea Basin           -15.1    0.54      8.81    0.51 Salmo salar
32 Trou du Frontal - Belgium Archaeological Europe     -14.2    0.08      9.76    0.2  Salmo salar
33 Knowth - Ireland          Archaeological Europe     -14.6    0         9.99    0    Salmo salar
34 Joseph Picard Site        Archaeological Canada     -19.9    0.41     10.3     0.2  Salmo salar
35 Summertown Site           Archaeological Canada     -16.1    0.51      9.89    0.06 Salmo salar
```

And when attempting to plot a bivariate plot with error bars, by Group and Catch Location Site (I'm aware there are repeating shapes in the following code, that's fine for what I need) using the following code:

```
Mean_Error_Comp_Salmon <- ggplot(Comp_Salmon, 
                                 aes(x=Mean_D13C, 
                                     y=Mean_D15N, 
                                     color=Group, 
                                     shape=Catch_Location_Site)) + 
  geom_point(size=5, stroke=2) + 
  xlab(expression(delta *"13C (‰)")) + 
  ylab (expression(delta *"15N (‰)")) +
  theme_cowplot(12) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=Mean_D15N - D15N_SD, ymax= Mean_D15N + D15N_SD)) +
  geom_errorbarh(aes(xmin= Mean_D13C - D13C_SD, xmax= Mean_D13C + D13C_SD)) +
  scale_color_viridis_d() +
  theme(text = element_text(size=26), 
        axis.text = element_text(size=26), 
        axis.ticks = element_line(linewidth = 1.5)) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = 
                       c("River Sella - Spain"=0, 
                         "River Bush - Ireland"= 1, 
                         "River Dee - England/Wales"=2, 
                         "River Frome - England"= 3, 
                         "Northeast UK Coast"=4,
                         "Koksoak River"=5,
                         "Conne River"=6,
                         "Big Salmon River"=7, 
                         "River Bush"=0, 
                         "Gaspereau River"=1, 
                         "Upper Salmon River"=2, 
                         "Dutch Wadden Sea"=3, 
                         "Loch Awe - Scotland"=4, 
                         "Lake Iijärvi - Finland"= 5,
                         "Näätämöjoki - Finland" = 6,
                         "Nuortijoki - Finland"=7, 
                         "Neidenelva - Norway"=0, 
                         "Neidenfjorden - Norway"=1,
                         "Gulf of St. Lawrence"=2, 
                         "Baffin Bay - Greenland"=3,
                         "Loch Ness - Scotland"=4,
                         "Coppergate - England"=5,
                         "Netherlands"=6,
                         "Ribe - Denmark"=7,
                         "Earl's Bu - Scotland"=0, 
                         "Trou du Frontal - Belgium"=1,
                         "Knowth - Ireland"=2,
                         "Joseph Picard Site"=3, 
                         "Summertown Site"=4))
Mean_Error_Comp_Salmon
```

I get the following warning:

```
Warning message:
Removed 1 rows containing missing values (`geom_point()`).
```

[Bivariate isotope plot with mean/error bars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4d2CS.png)

With this plot that, for some reason, has omitted 8 of my site locations. There are no NAs in any of the rows, every variable has data, so I'm not really sure what's going on here. I've tried checking the missing rows for spelling/character issues, extra spaces, everything. It's just 8 seemingly random rows which are missing, and though they're all from the same Group, so are others that are getting plotted.

Any advice, or glaringly obvious thing that I'm missing? Thanks in advance!

(Also, unpublished data disclaimer, yada yada, etc. etc.)

Comment: What shape has a value of zero?

Comment: The data you posted only contain 22 distinct catch locations.  Also, there is one location in the data that is not in the `scale_shape_manual()` list - `River Erne - Ireland` - this is the one that you get the warning for.   So, unless you're using different data than you posted, it appears that you're getting the right result.

Comment: Follow up:  Never mind, I am actually incredibly dense and just realized that the sites I was looking for don't have any salmon, they have trout and therefore shouldn't be showing up on the salmon plot.

Answer (score 0):

<unsolicited advice>

The bivariate differences between geographical clusters (instead of variability at the individual river spots) might become more obvious when visualized as below. Having the raw data, you could still add errorbars for groupwise variability, too.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(ggforce)
library(ggrepel)

d |>
  ggplot(aes(Mean_D13C, Mean_D15N)) +
  geom_mark_ellipse(aes(fill = Group, label = abbreviate(Group)),
                    alpha = .25, color = NA) +
  geom_point(aes(col = Group)) +
  geom_text_repel(aes(label = Catch_Location_Site), alpha = .5, size = 2) +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(.3, 0)) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(.3, 0)) +
  theme(legend.position = 'none')
```

</unsolicited advice>

[image: visualise bivariate clusters]

Comment: That's actually quite helpful! I've been trying to reverse-engineer a plot in R that was originally made with a combination of excel, powerpoint and photoshop so alternative ways of visualizing it are always appreciated. Cheers.

Comment: Yeah, there's always a catch in fish research ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I was using the wrong data the whole time, leaving this here for posterity and as a reminder to double check my data in the future.